# OpenFlow set_tunnel sends raw traffic with OVS

Tags: openvswitch

I'm trying to set up VXLAN on OVS using key:flow but, it doesn't seem to work.
my vxlan tunnel configuration

```
#host1
ovs-vsctl add-port h1-tun h2-vtep
ovs-vsctl set Interface h2-vtep type=vxlan option:remote_ip=20.20.20.220
ovs-vsctl set Interface h2-vtep ofport_request=15
ovs-vsctl set Interface h2-vtep option:key=flow
#host2
ovs-vsctl add-port h2-tun h1-vtep
ovs-vsctl set Interface h1-vtep type=vxlan option:remote_ip=10.10.10.220
ovs-vsctl set Interface h1-vtep ofport_request=15
ovs-vsctl set Interface h1-vtep option:key=flow
```

and I added OpenFlow rules to match and set_tunnel with this

```
#adding flows to h1-tun
ovs-ofctl add-flow h1-tun table=0,in_port=1,actions='resubmit(,1)'
ovs-ofctl add-flow h1-tun table=1,dl_vlan=10,actions=strip_vlan,set_tunnel:100,'resubmit(,2)'
ovs-ofctl add-flow h1-tun table=2,tun_id=100,dl_dst="$vm2_red_mac",actions=output:15
ovs-ofctl add-flow h1-tun table=2,arp,actions=output:15
ovs-ofctl add-flow h1-tun table=0,in_port=15,actions='resubmit(,3)'
ovs-ofctl add-flow h1-tun table=3,tun_id=100,actions=mod_vlan_vid:10,output:1
#adding flows to h2-tun
ovs-ofctl add-flow h2-tun table=0,in_port=1,actions='resubmit(,1)'
ovs-ofctl add-flow h2-tun table=1,dl_vlan=5,actions=strip_vlan,set_tunnel:100,'resubmit(,2)'
ovs-ofctl add-flow h2-tun table=2,tun_id=100,dl_dst="$vm1_red_mac",actions=output:15
ovs-ofctl add-flow h2-tun table=2,arp,actions=output:15
ovs-ofctl add-flow h2-tun table=0,in_port=15,actions='resubmit(,3)'
ovs-ofctl add-flow h2-tun table=3,tun_id=100,actions=mod_vlan_vid:5,output:1
```

when the VM creates arp traffic it goes out of OpenFlow port 15 but without being tunneled so, it is dropped by the router.

Comment: What's the purpose of the second rule of table 2 (the one on ARP)? Does it match any packets??

Comment: I use it to forward arp traffic to the other host. It does match. It is the rule that forwards the traffic in my case.